# Transferring objects between azure worker roles

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles

I'm trying to find a good way to send objects between the worker roles of two different azure applications. They are very simple objects(only about 20 properties on each one) and there could be as many as 10,000 of these objects transferred at a time. I'm thinking azure table storage would do the job, but I am not sure if theres anything else out there that would do a better job. I thought about serializing them and using blob storage, but Id like to know what the correct approach would be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Azure Table Storage is an excellent system for that.  If you need to manage which worker role processes individual items, you might consider using a Queue to communicate between the worker roles.  Microsoft Patterns and Practices created the "[CQRS Journey](http://aka.ms/pnpcqrs)" set of documentation to formalize how you can manage the flow of data through your Azure services with multiple roles.

Comment: Yeah, that looks about right. And the project in CQRS Journey looks like some good reading material.